# wordpress archive a user

Tags: php, wordpress, archive

I apologize if this can be answered elsewhere. I tried searching around with no answers. This may be due to my choice or words for searching or lack of understanding with WordPress.

I am a developer, but rather new to WordPress (and PHP in general).
one of the dev's has left who maintained the WordPress sites so I am now trying to add amendments without having someone in the office for additional guidance.

**our client has asked for a feature to auto-archive users who have not logged in for 4 months**. I am sure this is possible by adding additional columns and PHP code to verify login, but I would like to know a "good" way of implementing this. Is there a recommended add-on?

I see answers about archiving pages/posts, but would like to archive at user level.
I have noticed a column named user_status in the wp_users table but does not appear to be used.

*The "auto" part to the question I am not concerned about here. Should be able to achieve this with a simple daily Cron job.*

Any suggestion and/or pointers would be appreciated.
Any further queries, I will reply back as soon as I can.

thanks.

Comment: You can try the [Wordpress Development Stack Exchange](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/) or the [Wordpress Support](https://wordpress.org/support/). My first guess is that you will have to create your own custom plugin if there is no such plugin available at Wordpress.org.

Comment: Hi Nikolas -- I will ask this question on Wordpress Development Stack Exchange. To the moderators, please feel free to terminate this question.  Thanks,